# If $f\in L^1(0,\infty)$ and $f>0$ then $F(x)=\frac{1}{x}\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt \notin L^1(0,\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I want to prove the following statement

> If $f\in L^1(0,\infty)$ and $f>0$ then
>   $F(x)=\frac{1}{x}\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt \notin L^1(0,\infty)$

Frankly, I still have no solid idea how to prove this. Following are some things that I figured out.

$$F(x)=\frac{1}{x}\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt =\int_{0}^{1}f(xt)dt$$ We also have that $\int_0^{\infty}f(x)dx<\infty$. Therefore, $$\int_0^{\infty}F(x)dx=\int_0^{\infty}\Bigg(\int_{0}^{1}f(xt)dt\Bigg)dx=\int_0^1\Bigg(\int_0^{\infty}f(xt)dx\Bigg)dt$$

Since we know that $\int_0^{\infty}f(xt)dx<0$ what can we say about $\displaystyle\int_0^1\Bigg(\int_0^{\infty}f(xt)dx\Bigg)dt$? Any help is much appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Your $x$ and $t$ are mesed up.

Comment: @zhw. I don't see how. Can you show me?

Comment: The upper limit of the integral.

Comment: @zhw. Oh no! Thank you! I fixed it

Comment: @Heisenberg: You abused the notation. For greatest clarity, one should write: Define $F:(0,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $F(x) = \frac{1}{x}\int_0^x f(t)\,dt$, then $F\notin L^1(0,\infty)$. Remember that $F(x)$ is a "real number", so it is inappropriate to write $F(x)\notin L^1(0,\infty)$. This is especially true in the area of real analysis/functional analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f>0$, we have $\alpha:=\int_{0}^{1}f(t)\,dt>0$. For any $x\geq1$,
we have $F(x)\geq\frac{\alpha}{x}$. Hence $\int_{0}^{\infty}F(x)\,dx\geq\int_{1}^{\infty}F(x)\,dx\geq\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\alpha}{x}\,dx=\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: There exists $x_0>0$ such that $F(x) > \dfrac{1}{x}\cdot \dfrac{\int_0^\infty f}{2}$ for $x>x_0.$

Comment: I will think about this

Comment: Are you saying here that $xF(x)$ diverges when $x\to \infty$

Comment: @Heisenberg No of course not. $xF(x) \to \int_0^\infty f$

Comment: How come such a $x_0$ exists then?

Comment: @Heisenberg Notice the factor of a $1/2$.